# Fast splitting of dynamic_bitset in C++

Tags: c++, boost, bit-manipulation

I think the title is pretty much self-explaining. I have a boost::dynamic_bitset in my code, and I wish todo a fast split on it. Currently, I'm using a for loop to do it, but I'm pretty sure there is some faster way to do it, using bitwise operators.
For example:

```
B = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
```

And I want to remove B[2..5]:

```
B2 = [0 0 0 1]
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do it with masks, shifts, and resizes:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> B(10);
B[1] = 1;
B[5] = 1;
B[6] = 1;
B[7] = 1;
B[9] = 1;

boost::dynamic_bitset<> mask(B.size(), 0xf << 2);
boost::dynamic_bitset<> B2(B.size());

B2 = (B & mask) >> 2;
B2.resize(4);
```

Comment: Could you please explain better how it works? To be more specific, how the line

boost::dynamic_bitset<> mask(B.size(), 0xf << 2);

What does the 2 means? The rest of the code is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: << 2 just shifts the bits left two places. Since you're interested in bits 2-5, we create a mask of 4 1's (0xf) and shift it over by 2 places. Then we apply the mask, and shift the result back by those two places so we can deal with the bits of interest by themselves.

Comment: Great. So, for example, if I was in need of bits 4~10, I would shift the mask by 4, right?

Comment: Yep exactly, both places (shift the mask over, then shift the result after the mask is applied back)

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy the bits you want to keep into a new bitset.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
int main() 
{
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> B(10); 
    //Set bits, default is 0
    B[1] = 1;
    B[5] = 1;
    B[6] = 1;
    B[7] = 1;
    B[9] = 1;
    //Print out current bitset
    std::cout << "B: ";
    for (boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i)
      std::cout << B[i];

    std::cout << "\n";
    //Create a new bitset
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> B2(6); 
    B2[0] = B[0];
    B2[1] = B[1];
    B2[2] = B[6];
    B2[3] = B[7];
    B2[4] = B[8];
    B2[5] = B[9];

    //Print out B2
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << B2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that was pretty obvious. It makes no sense to do it if I know, at compile time, which bits are set. Any option on arbitrary-sized bitsets, and that are set on runtime?